# Serialization of 'DOMDocument' is not allowed in Laravel 10 mail with Pdf attachment

Tags: laravel

I am working with Laravel Mail. I want to send a PDF attachment using Laravel 10 mail documentation method. I get the above error message even after trying the closure base job. I have tried a closure base job, but it is still not working.

```
public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $customer = Customer::findOrFail(session('customerid'));

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF.customerappointmentpdf', 
        compact([ 'customer', 'appointment']));

    $job = function ($job) use ($customer, $pdf)
    {
        Mail::to($customer->email)->send(new CustomerAppointment($customer, $pdf));
        $job->delete();
    };

    Queue::push($job);
    
    return redirect()->route('customerappointments.index')
        ->with('status', 'You have successful booked an appointment.');
}
```